# convert int[] to byte array and byte array to image

Tags: java, image

Trying to store to an image.
bt is byte array

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bt);
Image img = ImageIO.read(is);
ImageIO.write(img,"jpg",new File("C:\\home_loan.jpg") );
```

, please help me,

error - 
: cannot find symbol

symbol  : method write(java.awt.Image,java.lang.String,java.io.File)

location: class javax.imageio.ImageIO

ImageIO.write(img,"jpg",new File("C:\home_loan.jpg") );

```
   ^
```

Comment: i m new tothis site so i dont know how to format sry

Comment: For code one needs to indent the code 4 spaces.

Comment: In your original post, you had an extra `}` brace somewhere in the middle. What is the compiletime or runtime error are you having ? Or is it a logic error ?

Comment: cannot find symbol   symbol  : method write(java.awt.Image,java.lang.String,java.io.File)
location: class javax.imageio.ImageIO
                ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg",outputfile );

Comment: what is rgb and why is it int[]?

Comment: How to do the conversion depends on where the int[] came from to begin with, but whatever format it's in I'm pretty sure that Java serialization is not the right way.

Comment: rgb contains pixel info..

Comment: ya,ithink so that pblm is in----                                       File outputfile = new File("aak.jpeg");

        ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg",outputfile );

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know whether the mapping is one int to one byte or one int to multiple bytes (and how many).  Then, if the latter, you need to know whether big-endian or little-endian.

For images you also need to have a clue as to what the image format is (and JPG actually has several variants).

Comment: pls  tell me what to change in this above code so that i can save image

Comment: img needs to be a RenderedImage (read the spec for ImageIO.write).

Comment: (Change `Image img` to `BufferedImage img`.  BufferedImage implements the RenderedImage interface.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). That is an Image backed by memory, and has two `setRGB` methods.

Tailor your data by that; otherwise you need to convert the data structure, working on one single BufferedImage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods-

```
/**
 * @param path full path of image
 * @return image file for supplied path
 */
private BufferedImage getImage(String path) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    File file = new File(path);
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}

/**
 * @param userSpaceImage 
 * @return byte array of supplied image
 */
private byte[] getByteData(BufferedImage userSpaceImage) {
    WritableRaster raster = userSpaceImage.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
    return buffer.getData();
}

/**
 * @param image image-file to save
 * @param file to save image to
 * @param extension of image file
 * @return full path of saved image
 */
private String saveImage(BufferedImage image, File file, String extension) {
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, extension, file);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```